# Given the tethraedron $OABC$ find ratio between its Volume and $\vert \vec{OM} \cdot \vec{ON} \times \vec{OP} \vert$

Tags: analytic-geometry

> Given the tethraedron $OABC$ where $\vec{OA} = \vec{a}$, $\vec{OB} = \vec{b}$ and $\vec{OC} = \vec{c}$ and the points $M$, $N$ and $P$, which are the midpoints of segments $\vec{AC}$, $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$ respectively, find the ratio between $\vert \vec{OM} \cdot \vec{ON} \times \vec{OP} \vert $ and the volume of the tethraedron $V$.

My approach was:

$$
\vec{OM} = \vec{OA} + \frac{1}{2} \vec{AC} = \vec{a} + \frac{1}{2} (- \vec{a} + \vec{c}) = \frac{\vec{a}}{2} + \frac{\vec{c}}{2}\\
\vec{ON} = \cdots = \frac{\vec{a}}{2} + \frac{\vec{b}}{2}\\
\vec{OP} = \cdots = \frac{\vec{c}}{2} + \frac{\vec{b}}{2}\\
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
\vert \vec{OM} \cdot \vec{ON} \times \vec{OP} \vert &= \left\vert \left( \frac{\vec{a}}{2} + \frac{\vec{c}}{2} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{\vec{a}}{2} + \frac{\vec{b}}{2} \right) \times \left( \frac{\vec{c}}{2} + \frac{\vec{b}}{2} \right) \right\vert\\
&= \frac{1}{8} \left\vert \left( \vec{a} + \vec{c} \right) \cdot \left( \vec{a} + \vec{b} \right) \times \left( \vec{c} + \vec{b} \right) \right\vert\\
&= \frac{1}{8} \left\vert (\vec{a} + \vec{c}) \cdot (\vec{a} \times \vec{c} + \vec{a} \times \vec{b} + \vec{b} \times \vec{c} + 0) \right\vert
\\
&= \frac{1}{8} \left\vert \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} \times \vec{c} + \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} \times \vec{b} + \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \times \vec{c} + \vec{c} \cdot \vec{a} \times \vec{c} + \vec{c} \cdot \vec{a} \times \vec{b} + \vec{c} \cdot \vec{b} \times \vec{c} \right\vert\\
&= \frac{1}{8} \left\vert 2 \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \times \vec{c} \right\vert\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left\vert \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \times \vec{c} \right\vert
\end{align*}
$$

Since

$$V = \frac{1}{6} \left\vert \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \times \vec{c} \right\vert
$$

then

$$
\frac{\vert \vec{OM} \cdot \vec{ON} \times \vec{OP} \vert }{V} = \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{6}} = \frac{3}{2}
$$

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

**Textbook's answer:** $\vert \vec{OM} \cdot \vec{ON} \times \vec{OP} \vert = \frac{3}{4} V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $[X]$ denote the volume of a $3$-dimensional object $X$, and $\langle Y\rangle$ the area of a $2$-dimensional object $Y$.  Then, $$[OMNP]=\frac{1}{6}\Biggl|\overrightarrow{OM}\cdot\Big(\overrightarrow{ON}\times\overrightarrow{OP}\Big)\Biggr|\,.$$
Note that the tetrahedra $OMNP$ and $OABC$ share a common altitude (from the point $O$).  Since $MNP$ and $ABC$ are similar triangles with $\frac{MN}{BC}=\frac{NP}{CA}=\frac{PM}{AB}=\frac{1}{2}$, we get
$$\frac{[OMNP]}{[OABC]}=\frac{\langle MNP\rangle }{\langle ABC\rangle}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac14\,,$$
That is,
$$\frac{\Biggl|\overrightarrow{OM}\cdot\Big(\overrightarrow{ON}\times\overrightarrow{OP}\Big)\Biggr|}{V}=6\left(\frac{[OMNP]}{[OABC]}\right)=\frac{6}{4}=\frac{3}{2}\,.$$
So, you are correct, and the mistake is in the textbook.

Comment: Thank you @Batominovski, I appreaciate that. Would you mind looking at my other recently-opened question? Thank you, best regards!